# What is w componet

Tags: opengl, 3d, graphics, opengl-es2

What is the W component on graphics programming. I read a blog about opengl that says that w must be equal to either 0 or 1 [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/#Homogeneous_coordinates). But the book I am currently reading has put w component to more than 1 value. So im kinda confuse what does it really do. The book I am reading is OpenGL es a quick start guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to the affine transformation matrix.  Basically, a `0` means that you are working with a *vector* (which has no position and is not affected by the affine portion of transformation matrices) and a `1` means that you are working with a *point* (which is affected by affine transformations).

Consider this 3x3 column-major 2D affine translation matrix:

```
1 0 5
0 1 3
0 0 1
```

If you apply this to the vector `<2, 4, 0>` then when the matrix rows are multiplied we get:

```
2 0 0 = 2
0 4 0 = 4
0 0 0 = 0
```

And the result is the input vector.  No affine translation applied.  This is exactly what we want: you can't "move" a vector.

Now let's apply this to the *point* `(7, 8, 1)`:

```
7 0 5 = 12
0 8 3 = 11
0 0 1 = 1
```

And we get the point `(12, 11, 1)` which is the original point plus the translation portion of the matrix, which again is exactly what we want.

You will notice that the `w` component stays the same based on the input; that is, transforming a vector produces a vector and transforming a point produces a point.

There are additional benefits to this simple math.  Think of the operations of adding or substracting vectors or subtracting points.  Two vectors added or subtracted create a resulting vector.

```
  1 2 0
+ 5 3 0
= 6 5 0
```

Likewise, with subtraction, the math works out.

Now, let's substract two points.  We know that this should result in a vector (the difference between the points) and not another point.  Conveniently:

```
  5 3 1
- 1 2 1
= 4 1 0
```

Perfect.  Of course, if you add two points together then you end up with a `w` of 2, but then adding points is not a legal operation (it has no meaningful result).  Adding a point to a vector should result in a new point, which of course works:

```
  5 3 1
+ 4 4 0
= 9 7 1
```

Everything works out.  The `w` component perfectly encodes whether we have a *point* or a *vector* and simultaneously allows the application of affine transformation matrices correctly for vectors vs points.  This allows the use of a single transformation matrix for both points and vectors, which is useful when we want to apply it to both vertex positions (points) and vertex normals (vectors) or the like.

Comment: Just adding the keyword [Homogeneous Coordinates](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) to a good explanation.